# Why am i getting authors, titles, abstract and journals first and then appearing together? They should be together per title.

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull out information from an html file of the link http://dl.acm.org/results.cfm?CFID=376026650&CFTOKEN=88529867. For every Paper title, i need the authors, journal name and abstract. But i am getting repetitive versions of each first before getting them together. Please help. Meaning i am first getting a list of titles, then authors, then journals, then abstract, and then i get them together per title, as in title first, then the respective authors, journal name, and the abstract. I only need them together, not individually.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests
import re

f = open('acmpage.html', 'r') #open html file stores locally
html = f.read() #read from the html file and store the content in 'html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
pret = soup.prettify()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(pret)
for content in soup1.find_all("table"):
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(content))
    pret2 = soup2.prettify()
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(pret2)

    for titles in soup3.find_all('a', target = '_self'): #to print title
        print "Title: ", 
        print titles.get_text()
    for auth in soup3.find_all('div', class_ = 'authors'): #to print authors
        print "Authors: ", 
        print auth.get_text()
    for journ in soup3.find_all('div', class_ = 'addinfo'): #to print name of journal
        print "Journal: ", 
        print journ.get_text()
    for abs in soup3.find_all('div', class_ = 'abstract2'): # to print abstract
        print "Abstract: ", 
        print abs.get_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for each list of information separately, there is little question as to *why* you see each type of information listed separately.

Your code is also full of redundancies; you only need to import *one* version of BeautifulSoup (the first import is shadowed by the second), and you don't need to re-parse the elements 2 times either. You import *two different* URL loading libraries then ignore both by loading a local file instead.

Search for the table rows *containing* the title information instead, then per table row, parse out the information contained.

For this page, with its more complex (and frankly, disorganized) layout with multiple tables, it'd be easiest just to go up to the table row per title link found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

resp = requests.get('http://dl.acm.org/results.cfm', 
                    params={'CFID': '376026650', 'CFTOKEN': '88529867'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, from_encoding=resp.encoding)

for title_link in soup.find_all('a', target='_self'):
    # find parent row to base rest of search of
    row = next(p for p in title_link.parents if p.name == 'tr')
    title = title_link.get_text()
    authors = row.find('div', class_='authors').get_text()
    journal = row.find('div', class_='addinfo').get_text()
    abstract = row.find('div', class_='abstract2').get_text()
```

The `next()` call loops over a generator expression that goes over each parent of the title link until a `<tr>` element is found.

Now you have all the information grouped *per title*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the first addinfo div, then creep forward to find the publisher in a div further on in the document.  You will need to go up the tree to the enclosing tr, then get the next sibling for the consecutive tr.  Then search inside that tr for the next data item ( the publisher).

Once you have done this for all the items you need to display, issue a single print command for all the items you've found